# Modify text of Footer of a docx (MS Word 2013) file

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

I am using DocX library to modify a word file. I replaced a text in this document as follow:

```
using (DocX document = DocX.Load(@"E:\Test.docx"))
{
    document.ReplaceText("text", "replaced");
    document.Save();
}
```

But, texts in Footer of the file are not replaced. The question is *How can I modify texts in the Footer of the docx file?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace texts of footer using `Footer` property for both `even` and `odd` likes the following:

```
// ...
document.Footers.odd?.ReplaceText("text","replaced");
document.Footers.even?.ReplaceText("text","replaced");

document.Save();
```